# Rewrite rules for apache

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Given this link: localhost/app/forms/enroll.php.
I want it to render when i access /register.

For example: localhost/register will display localhost/app/forms/enroll.php

so basically I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule register app/forms/enroll.php
```

In my code I have a call to localhost/enroll.php which i would want to redirect to /app/enroll.php but then I want to display the link (localhost/register) again.

So i need to call back again the RewriteRule i made above.

adding this rule doesn't work

```
RewriteRule enroll.php register [R]
```

also this one

```
RewriteRule enroll.php app/forms/enroll.php [C]
RewriteRule app/forms/enroll.php register
```

note: I need a workaround with this instead of having to change the links in the code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, you don't have to redirect several times. Just map silently the first time, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !enroll.php         [NC]
RewriteRule ^register/?$  app/forms/enroll.php  [L]
```

It will redirect silently

`http://localhost/register`  (This URL is always shown in the browser)

To:

`http://localhost/app/forms/enroll.php`